# Word for a group of customers who only take advantage of company's services

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a single word to describe a group of customers, who merely take advantage of the company's services (they come only for free period and leave afterwards or take the gift and leave again).

So far I came up with a term `Profiteers`, but this is somewhat pejorative, which is not what I want.

Comment: Using the word 'merely' implies a pejorative, too.  Your single word could include 'loss-leader-feeders' or 'teaser-seizers.'

Comment: It might not be possible to come up with a word that *isn't* pejorative. I would guess that even if you invented one, it would become pejorative through use.

Comment: What's wrong with "customers"?  They're behaving exactly like you encouraged them to behave.

Comment: There totally should be a positive word for freeloaders and coupon clippers. As Hot Licks says, *every* customer takes advantage of services, that's what the word "services" *means*, and that's what the concept of "advantage" is all about. If a company chooses to offer a service for free, that's their decision, and it makes economic sense to every customer to get stuff for free rather than for not-free. More to the point, it's not like the company does it for selfless reasons, it makes economic sense *to them* as well. The non-returning customers are a sunk cost. Always part of the equation.

Comment: I agree that the behaviour is, in fact, logical and there is nothing wrong with it. But every company has many types of customer. And since we can call `loyals` those who are really engaged and believe in the company, I am looking for a name for the opposite behaviour, the `profiteers`.

Comment: I think the problem with *profiteer* isn't that it is pejorative, but that it already has a defined meaning which isn't a particularly close fit for the usage. have you considered 'browsers', 'gatherers' or 'gleaners'?

Comment: Well, you could always call them "rational customers".

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. For my purpose, words such as `surfers`, or `samplers` are the most suitable. They express the not-so-loyal behavior, yet it sounds positive.

Comment: Why is it that companies do not award their loyal customers with these same deals?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific context of *credit cards*, the word “tart” (in the sense of prostitute) is used in combination with **rate** or **card** (at least in Britain). Thus, on [macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/rate-tart.html):

> **rate tart**
>
> noun [countable]
>
> 1. *also* **card tart** or **card surfer** 
>    someone who continually switches credit card providers in order to get the lowest interest rates
>    available

Sorry, it’s not a single word, but the combinations represent specific usage. (And it’s not plural either, but you can add an ‘s’ if you like.)

Comment: I like the word `surfer`, which is expressing the unstability in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is Sampler, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sampler).  It's certainly non-pejorative, and many retailers, such as Amazon, refer to their giveaways as Samples (in their Kindle Books section).

> Definition of sampler 
>   1
>   :  one that collects, prepares, or examines samples

Answer (score -1):

[Transient(s)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transient) might fit your needs:

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Lasting only for a short time; impermanent.
>
> 1.1 Staying or working in a place for a short time only.

and

> NOUN
>
> 1. A person who is staying or working in a place for a short time only.

Comment: A comment explaining the downvotes might help improve the quality of future answers.

Answer (score -1):

I like the term fleeting for this usage.

> [Fleeting](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fleeting) - passing swiftly; vanishing quickly; transient; transitory:

It know it doesn't fit perfectly but it closely describes people who drifted away from my product after the free trial period.

Or you could use Itinerant.

> [Itinerant](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/itinerant) - a person who travels from place to place, especially for duty or business.

This could mean that the person was only using your product only for completing an item before moving on with the process (to possibly someone else's product).